# Convert factor value into numeric in a column of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, character, numeric

I have a data frame that has two string characters stored in each row

```
s   ['64.0', '2']   
a   ['63.0', '2']   
b   ['63.0', '1']
```

How to convert the first character string into numeric value,and omit the second character string,which results into data frame as follows :

```
s    64.0   
a    63.0
b    63.0
```

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve]? It's unclear what those values are/what types of information you're trying to extract numbers from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `parse_number`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df2 <-  df1 %>%
          mutate(col2 = parse_number(as.character(col2)))
df2
#   col1 col2
#1    s   64
#2    a   63
#3    b   63
```

---

Or using `base R` with `sub`

```
as.numeric( sub("\\D+([0-9.]+)[^0-9]+.*", "\\1", df1$col2))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("s", "a", "b"), col2 = structure(3:1, .Label = c("['63.0', '1']", 
"['63.0', '2']", "['64.0', '2']"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: showing error : 
Error in parse_vector(x, col_number(), na = na, locale = locale, trim_ws = trim_ws) : 
  is.character(x) is not TRUE

Comment: @shome I was thinking that it is `character`.  Updated with `as.character`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R solution using `regmatches`, i.e.,

```
df <- within(df, col2 <- as.numeric(sapply(regmatches(col2,gregexpr("[0-9\\.]+",col2)),`[[`,1)))
```

such that

```
> df
  col1 col2
1    s   64
2    a   63
3    b   63
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `extract` from `tidyr`

```
tidyr::extract(df, col2, into = c('col2', 'col3'), "(\\d+\\.\\d+).*(\\d)")

#  col1 col2 col3
#1    s 64.0    2
#2    a 63.0    2
#3    b 63.0    1
```

You can then remove the columns which you don't need.